# react-redux react-router store not available in props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux, react-redux

I just started to use redux on my react site. Pretty small. (and I'm following this tutorial https://medium.com/front-end-developers/handcrafting-an-isomorphic-redux-application-with-love-40ada4468af4#.mhkgga84t plugging in some codes to my react site just in case). But when I was in progress and trying to acceess `this.props.store` it's not available even when I have `<Provider store={store}>` in my app. Here's my client and app code (I can provide more I just don't know what else to add):

```
// src/client.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router } from 'react-router';

import { routes } from './routes';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import * as reducers from './reducers';
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';

let initialState = window.__INITIAL_STATE__;

Object.keys(initialState).forEach(key => {
  initialState[key] = fromJS(initialState[key]);
});

const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);
const store = createStore(reducer, initialState);
console.log('store', store);

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><Router routes={routes} history={browserHistory} store={store} /></Provider>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

but I can't access `store` from `this.props`. It should be available here right? So I can do `const { todos, dispatch } = this.props;` eventually?

```
// src/components/app.js
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

import HeaderComponent from './common/header';
import ShareFooterComponent from './common/share-footer';
import FooterComponent from './common/footer';

import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as ListingActions from '../actions/listing';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default class AppComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log('apps', this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        <HeaderComponent />

        { this.props.children }

        <ShareFooterComponent />
        <FooterComponent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to be wiring up your state with the `connect` decorator. If I am reading the [tutorial](https://medium.com/front-end-developers/handcrafting-an-isomorphic-redux-application-with-love-40ada4468af4#.yld8q54l6) correctly you should include the line (or something similar based on your state structure):

```
@connect(state => ({ todos: state.todos }))
```

or without decorator syntax (more succint version in the comments):

```
AppComponent = connect(state => ({ todos: state.todos }), null)(AppComponent);
export default AppComponent;`
```

Comment: I tried to add this code before but I got an `unexpected error` in the `@connect` particularly the `@` sign. Then I tried to follow this http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html#-somecomponent-js and read that in SomeComponent.js it says `let { dispatch } = this.props // Injected by react-redux:` but doesn't appear.

Comment: Your build may not be setup for decorators i.e. `@func`. I think you'll need babel preset stage-0 for that. You can call connect function normally, it's a function of react-redux library if you want to read the docs. Your use case should look something like  `export default connect(state => ({ todos: state.todos }))(AppComponent)`

Comment: Okay. I found the `store` but it's in the `this.context` when I add `AppComponent.contextTypes = { store: React.PropTypes.object }` in the bottom. Should I use that one or try out `connect`?

Comment: `connect` is better, it does that stuff for you. One of the few problems I have with redux is the amount of boilerplate code you need, so I'd tend to use the _anointed_ helper functions at all times.

Comment: Awesome! The connect works. Thanks guys! Just in case, what am I missing to use the `@` sign?

Comment: [Babel Preset Stage-0](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/) will allow you to use decorators. You'll need to install the preset module and add it to your `.babelrc` file

Comment: Actually, decorators were removed from babel 6: https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T2645. There is a legacy package that is quite shaky (I've never used it): https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy . Or you can use Typescript. The timelines for the re-introduction of decorators last time I checked was essentially when the team (wycats in particular) believes the proposal is ready.

Comment: I see. Maybe I'll stick to this implementation for now. Better to learn core anyway.

Answer (score 2):

So first thing I noticed that does not seem right is you are passing the store to both the provider and the router

```
<Provider store={store}><Router routes={routes} history={browserHistory} store={store} /></Provider>
```

Where it would only be needed in Provider like

```
<Provider store={store}><Router routes={routes} history={browserHistory} /></Provider>
```

Then like Ashley Coolman said you will need to connect the component to redux. 
It can be done with the decorator if your build is set up for it. However you can also import the `connect` function from react-redux. Documentation on it can be found [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options).

The way I would hook up your component is the following

```
class AppComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log('apps', this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        <HeaderComponent />
        { this.props.children }
        <ShareFooterComponent />
        <FooterComponent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function addTodo(todo) {
    return { type: ADD_TODO, payload: todo }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    // the state is from store.getState()
    // example will pass a todos prop to the connected component
    // so if you want all the state in this component use the spread operator 
    return {
        todos: state.todos
    }
}


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    // bindActionCreators will wrap all the function in the passed in object 
    // with the dispatch function so that the actionCreators can be called 
    // directly; without dispatch eg this.props.addTodo(sometodo)
    return bindActionCreators({ addTodo }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppComponent )
```

After that you will have as props on your component both `addTodo` (function) and `todos`. Giving you

```
this.props.todos
this.props.addTodo()
```