# React-redux: Could not find "store"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, redux, react-router

I'm new to web development, and I'm having difficulty learning react, redux, express, and single-page routing so I apologize if I'm missing an obvious fix.

Here is the error I am getting in the server console: `Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Navbar)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Navbar)".`

I'm pretty sure that I am wrapping my root component in a `<Provider>` with a store.

I have seen other people report similar problems.

- In [one instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050963/react-redux-react-router-store-not-available-in-props), the user did not connect his component, but I
  think I'm connecting mine.
- In [another case](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/57), a workaround was given for React 0.13. However,
  I am using React 15, and I also tried the workaround and still had no
  luck.
- I eventually made my way to [redux's troubleshooting section](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#could-not-find-store-in-either-the-context-or-props).
  Unfortunately, I am using webpack and can't get its sourcemaps
  working so I can't confirm that I don't have duplicate react files
  running. I did do a search for react.js files in my node modules:

`find . -name 'react.js'
./node_modules/babel-types/lib/react.js
./node_modules/react/dist/react.js
./node_modules/react/react.js`

But if I deleted the react.js in babel-types, the webpack build
failed.

---

In my express server file, I'm using react-router's Router.match() to get a single-page application. If I instead use the following, then I don't get any problems with the store, but my app no longer appears to be a single-page app. If I'm wrong about this, then this would seem to be the solution. However, I'm concerned that it GET requests all the static files every time I visit a new url, but I might be confusing my idea of what a SPA really is.

```
app.get('/*', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views/index.html'))
})
```

---

Here is a dump of my code:

### server.js

```js
// Babel ES6/JSX Compiler
require('babel-register');

var _ = require('underscore');
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');
var swig  = require('swig');
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom/server');
var Router = require('react-router');
var routes = require('./app/routes');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Trip = require('./models/trip');
var config = require('./config');

mongoose.connect(config.database);
mongoose.connection.on('error', function() {
  console.info('Error: Could not connect to MongoDB. Did you forget to run `mongod`?');
});

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


/** 
 * POST /api/trips
 * Adds new trip to database.
 */
app.post('/api/trips', function(req, res, next) {
    var destination = req.body.destination;
    var startDate = req.body.startDate;
    var endDate = req.body.endDate;
    var comment = req.body.comment;

    var trip = new Trip({
        destination: destination,
        startDate: startDate,
        endDate: endDate,
        comment: comment
    });

    trip.save(function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        res.send({message: "Trip to " + destination + " has been added successfully!"});
    });

});

/**
 * GET /api/trips
 * Returns all trips
 */
app.get('/api/trips', function(req, res, next) {
    Trip.find()
        .exec(function(err, trips) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }

            return res.send(trips);
        })
});

/**
 * PUT /api/trips/:id
 * Updates trip given by id
 */
app.put('/api/trips/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    // TODO
});

/**
 * GET /api/trips/:id
 * Returns trip given by id
 */
app.get('/api/trips/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    // TODO
});

/**
 * DELETE /api/trips/:id
 * Deletes trip given by id
 */
app.delete('/api/trips/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    // TODO
});



app.use(function(req, res) {
    Router.match({routes: (routes.default)(), location: req.url}, function(err, redirectLocation, renderProps) {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send(err.message)
        } else if (redirectLocation) {
          res.status(302).redirect(redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
        } else if (renderProps) {
          var html = ReactDOM.renderToString(React.createElement(Router.RouterContext, renderProps));
          var page = swig.renderFile('views/index.html', { html: html });
          res.status(200).send(page);
        } else {
          res.status(404).send('Page Not Found')
        }
    });
});

var server = https.createServer(options, app);

server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

### views/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
  <title>Trip Planner</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,900"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/_datepicker.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="/js/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="/js/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### main.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Router, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import routes from './routes';
import tripPlanner from './reducers/tripPlanner';

let store = createStore(tripPlanner);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            {routes}
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app'));
```

### reducers/tripPlanner.js

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';
import navbar from './navbar';
import trips from './trips';

const tripPlanner = combineReducers({
    trips,
    navbar,
    form: formReducer
});

export default tripPlanner;
```

### routes.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Route} from 'react-router';
import App from './components/App';
import Home from './components/Home';
import AddTrip from './components/AddTrip';

export default (
    <Route component={App}>
        <Route path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route path='/add' component={AddTrip} />
    </Route>
);
```

### components/App.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import NavbarContainer from '../containers/NavbarContainer'

const App = (props) => (
  <div>
    <NavbarContainer />
    {props.children}
  </div>
)

export default App
```

### containers/NavbarContainer.js

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        ajaxAnimationClass: state.ajaxAnimationClass
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {

    }
}

const NavbarContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Navbar);

export default NavbarContainer;
```

### components/Navbar.js

```js
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

const Navbar = ({ ajaxAnimationClass }) => (
  <nav className='navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top'>
    <div className='navbar-header'>
      <button type='button' className='navbar-toggle collapsed' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#navbar'>
        <span className='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
        <span className='icon-bar'></span>
        <span className='icon-bar'></span>
        <span className='icon-bar'></span>
      </button>
      <Link to='/' className='navbar-brand'>
        <span ref='triangles' className={'triangles animated ' + ajaxAnimationClass}>
          <div className='tri invert'></div>
          <div className='tri invert'></div>
          <div className='tri'></div>
          <div className='tri invert'></div>
          <div className='tri invert'></div>
          <div className='tri'></div>
          <div className='tri invert'></div>
          <div className='tri'></div>
          <div className='tri invert'></div>
        </span>
        Trips
      </Link>
    </div>
    <div id='navbar' className='navbar-collapse collapse'>
      <ul className='nav navbar-nav'>
        <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='/add'>Add</Link></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
);

export default Navbar;
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "trip-planner",
  "description": "Trip planner",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "watch": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^1.5.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.22.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.14.1",
    "colors": "^1.1.2",
    "compression": "^1.6.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "history": "^1.13.0",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.2.5",
    "morgan": "^1.6.1",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.4.2",
    "react-datepicker": "^0.40.0",
    "react-dates": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.2",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-form": "^6.5.0",
    "request": "^2.65.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io": "^1.3.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "swig": "^1.4.2",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.1.19",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-register": "^6.3.13",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "bower": "^1.6.5",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "watchify": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

---

I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious and that this is such a long post, but I hope that it's useful in getting all the necessary information across. If you need anything else to help me, please let me know.

Comment: Can you try doing this for the Router component? <Router routes={routes} history={...} >

Comment: And I was wondering where you error is popping up? You mentioned server, but React is just frontend and that should appear in the browser console, not server-side console. Did you make sure to run webpack to bundle everything together (again) into bundle.js or something? Furthermore, if you replace the Provider in the ReactDOM injection with just a simple div with a message, and no problem occurs and you get the page with the message, then there's no issue with the bundling and sending the static assets to the client.

Comment: Hi nbkhope, thanks for the help. I tried your first comment and got the same result. For your second comment, the error message is appearing in my terminal and as the content of my browser, but not in the browser console which is blank. I tried replacing my <Provider> tag with <div> and got the same error too. I'm confident that I'm bundling with webpack.

Comment: Did you try putting your SPA in the public/ directory instead of sending it via an explicit controller response?

Comment: Thanks for the help nbkhope, I eventually tried replacing the <Provider> with a <div> and removed all the code that broke with this change. I then continued to add in code until I rediscovered the error and found the culprit

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: In your express server.js use for your routing:

```
app.get('/*', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views/index.html'))
})
```

If your app is no longer acting as a SPA and you want it to, fix your component declarations to look like `class MyComponent extends React.Component {...}`

---

I think I found a solution. I have to admit I don't know why exactly it works, but it does.

First of all, I was originally routing my app incorrectly in server.js like so:

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
    Router.match({routes: (routes.default)(), location: req.url}, function(err, redirectLocation, renderProps) {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send(err.message)
        } else if (redirectLocation) {
          res.status(302).redirect(redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
        } else if (renderProps) {
          var html = ReactDOM.renderToString(React.createElement(Router.RouterContext, renderProps));
          var page = swig.renderFile('views/index.html', { html: html });
          res.status(200).send(page);
        } else {
          res.status(404).send('Page Not Found')
        }
    });
});
```

The method I was using was based off a [tutorial](http://sahatyalkabov.com/create-a-character-voting-app-using-react-nodejs-mongodb-and-socketio/) that used alt.js instead of redux. I don't necessarily understand why redux requires you to route like so:

```
app.get('/*', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views/index.html'))
})
```

But doing this does get rid of the original error. However, when I tried using this method, I realized my application was no longer a Single-Page Application because it was sending GET requests for every new url. I discovered the solution by stripping my app down to simple divs without redux code. I eventually discovered that my problem was in Navbar.js (above in question). For whatever reason, when I changed the declaration from

```
const Navbar ({ajaxAnimationClass}) => {...}
```

to

```
class Navbar extends React.Component {...}
```

my app was no longer sending GET requests on every new page load.